# How tomcat loads a jar file?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

Putting a jar file under Tomcat/lib folder. And tomcat loads the jar file.

**My Question is:**

How does tomcat load a jar file? e.g. Unpack, then index it, look for the class and load it using reflection.. Which i can guess..

Is there any library in java from which i can make a similar application?

**My Objective:**

I have an java interface which will supposed to extend application capabilities. There is a default implementation. But, in the future, it will be changed and can have multiple copies/version.
 The idea is to provide implementation and pack it into a jar file and drop it into a folder. The container will look for the implementation and list down the implementation.

An End-User who use the application can choose default or any version...

Example: Default theme..

Now, i have an interface

```
public interface Theme
{
  public void setName();
  public void setColor();
  public void setBGColor(); 
  public void getName();
  public void getColor();
  public void getBGColor(); 
}
```

Admin created two theme i.e. BlueWITHGreenBGTheme and GreenWITHBlackBGTheme. Compiled it and packed it and drop into the folder..

End-User will now see three different theme :  Default Theme, BlueWITHGreenBGTheme and GreenWITHBlackBGTheme. He/She Choose any theme and his/her application color and background color change.

Above is just an example, not the real scenario.

Comment: This is rather a broad question, and it will likely be closed as such. You may want to do some background reading, a good starting point is the Java Service Provider Interface (SPI), it offers what I think you are looking for.

Comment: If you want to load the classes in a jar file that is not on the classpath, you could use the JarFile class to get the classnames and then use a custom classloader to load the classes so the analyzer could inspect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat uses a custom [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

You can make your own too but [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) satisfy the requisites of most developers.

Don't think URL are about internet, they may point to local jar files too.